# Python numpy scientific notation limit decimals

Tags: python, numpy, string-formatting, scientific-notation

I'm trying to reduce the number of decimals that I'm getting after some calculations. The `print()` where my problem arises looks like this:

```
print("Mean resistivity: {res} Ohm m".format(res=np.mean(resistivity)))
```

And it outputs this:

```
Mean resistivity: 1.6628449915450776e-08 Ohm m
```

Now I want to reduce the number of decimal places that are printed to 3. I tried doing it with string formatting, like this:

```
print("Mean resistivity: {res:.3f} Ohm m".format(res=np.mean(resistivity)))
```

However, this code prints:

```
Mean resistivity: 0.000 Ohm m
```

What I actually want is this:

```
Mean resistivity: 1.663e-8 Ohm m
```

How can I format `res` to only be displayed as scientific notation but with only 3 decimal places?

Comment: Use a format print [specifier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's python3? If so this should work: `{res:.3E}`

@edit
It should work also with python2 - [spec](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: Confirmed also in Python 3

Comment: Yes, thanks! It works :) Also works with a lowercase `e`. Going to bookmark that documentation

Comment: @Dartmouth you should be aware that when you move to python 3.x, there are slight enhancements to that found in the 2.x documentation.  Also, note that python 3.6 (when it arrives soon) has an even simpler implementation that shares the same mini-formatting language.  bookmark this for the future... https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings